# Join DataFrames, but keep only columns of one

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `DataFrame` `df1`:

```
| ID | A |
---------
| 1  | 4 |
| 1  | 4 |
| 2  | 1 |
| 2  | 3 |
| 3  | 2 |
```

and a `DataFrame` `df2`:

```
| ID | B |
---------
| 1  | 2 |
| 2  | 2 |
| 3  | 9 |
```

I want to (left) join these, but only want to keep the columns of `df2`.
What is a short and easy solution for this?

The resulting `DataFrame` should look somehow like this:

```
|ID | B |
---------
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 9 |
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could slice the ID column from `df1` as a DataFrame and merge on ID:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3],
                    'A': [4, 4, 1, 2, 3]
                    })

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 2, 3],
                    'B': [2, 2, 9]
                    })


merged = df1[['ID']].merge(df2, how='left')
```

This returns a DataFrame of the form:

```
   ID  B
0   1  2
1   1  2
2   2  2
3   2  2
4   3  9
```

Comment: This is especially useful if that dataframe has unneeded columns with the same names as the columns you are removing.

Comment: Simple but effective solution.

Answer (score 3):

perform the join and pick up only columns in `df2`

```
df2.merge(df1, on='ID')[df2.columns]
# output:
   B  ID
0  2   1
1  2   1
2  2   2
3  2   2
4  9   3
```

Comment: [The other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45061616/1048186) is much cleaner than this one because it cleans the unneeded columns out BEFORE the merge.  If an unneeded column matches a non-"on" column in the main dataframe, both columns will be renamed, making selection by column name difficult.